# Выводить null если в таблице нет такой записи

Tags: sql, postgresql

Я делаю запрос

```
SELECT T1.TABLE1_ID, T2.TABLE2_ID, T3.TABLE3_ID
FROM TABLE1 AS T1, TABLE2 AS T2, TABLE3 AS T3
WHERE T1.TABLE1_ID = 12 AND T2.TABLE2_ID = 32 AND T3.TABLE3_ID = 37
```

Получаю результат:

```
 TABLE1_ID | TABLE2_ID | TABLE3_ID |
------------------------------------
     12    |     32    |     37    |
```

Все хорошо. Проблема возникает когда в одной из трех таблиц нет `id`.

Например в `TABLE3` нет записи с `id` равным 50;

```
SELECT T1.TABLE1_ID, T2.TABLE2_ID, T3.TABLE3_ID
FROM TABLE1 AS T1, TABLE2 AS T2, TABLE3 AS T3
WHERE T1.TABLE1_ID = 12 AND T2.TABLE2_ID = 32 AND T3.TABLE3_ID = 50
```

Я получаю результат:

```
 TABLE1_ID | TABLE2_ID | TABLE3_ID |
------------------------------------
```

Так как нет записи с `id` равным 50 в таблице `TABLE3`.

А мне надо получить:

```
 TABLE1_ID | TABLE2_ID | TABLE3_ID |
------------------------------------
     12    |     32    |   null    |
```

Как можно это реализовать? Так же это может произойти и с таблицей `TABLE1` и `TABLE3`, так и со всеми тремя таблицами

Comment: А какой смысл в ТАКОМ запросе? Куда как проще сделать `SELECT 12 AS TABLE1_ID, 32 AS TABLE2_ID, 37 AS TABLE3_ID;` и не заморачиваться на наличие чего-то где-то... Или это просто неудачная "модель"? Лучше покажите реальные структуры и запрос...

Comment: Замените запятые в FROM на синтаксис LEFT JOIN, условия соединения таблиц перенесите из where в требуемые ON у эти left join

Comment: @Mike Так нет у него никакого соединения таблиц, вот в чём фигня-то. Он просто хочет одним запросом проверить существование заданных ID в нескольких таблицах...

Comment: @Akina Хм, не обратил внимания ... Тогда да, ждем что ответит ТС на ваш первый коммент и пояснит чего он на самом деле пытается достичь...

Comment: @Akina Как правильно сделать? У меня есть три таблицы, мне надо найти в них ид.

Comment: `select (select id from t1 where id=12) id1, (select id from t2 ...), ...`

Comment: Видимо, не найти, а проверить наличие заданных ID? ну так, судя по тексту... Это разные задачи.

Comment: @Mike На всякий случай я бы добавил DISTINCT - а ну как он не в уникальном поле ищет...

Comment: Если надо узнать существование строки - тогда `select exists(select id from t1 where id=12) id1,` и получить простой bool без всяких пересортировок на distinct.